# how to use ZAP JxBrowser in ZAP selenium?

Tags: selenium, security, owasp, zap

Currently, we use python selenium to launch firefox, and also configure the firefox proxy setting to go through ZAP proxy.

```
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
capabilities['proxy'] = {
            'proxyType': "manual",
            'httpProxy': "127.0.0.1:8080",
            'ftpProxy': "127.0.0.1:8080",
            'sslProxy': "127.0.0.1:8080"
            }

self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

But I also see ZAP contains its own browser, JxBrowser

How to use JxBrowser in ZAP seleium...? is there any document about that ?

Let's say, if we login the site with seleium, how could I trigger the spider to scan all the post login pages...? Could ZAP helps me to do that..?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JxBrowser as one of the options with the ZAP ajax spider.

We havnt added an option to launch JxBrowser outside of ZAP as this might break the licensing agreement we have with them - see https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/wiki/HelpAddonsJxbrowserJxbrowser#licensing for more details. However I'd have no problem launching JxBrowser from ZAP for the user to control via selenium, we'd just need to work out a way to do it that allows the user to take control.

Logging in with selenium and then launching the ZAP spider is a good option. ZAP has a powerful API that allows you to control nearly all of the ZAP features. In this case you'll probably need to find and flag the session the selenium tests started as 'active' - see https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/wiki/HelpStartConceptsHttpsessions for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your response ! is there any way to automate the JxBrowser in ZAP seleium with ZAPv2 API ...?

Comment: Not at the moment. What interface would you like to have? We'd need to work out how to pass control from ZAP to the client...

Comment: our team want to implement ZAPv2 script in our SDLC..... it will be nice if ZAP could spider the post-login pages if we successfully login the site. If JxBrowser could be automated, then session could be controlled in JxBrowser.... and spider will be much easier..?

Comment: Raise a feature request: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/new?labels=enhancement&template=Feature_request.md we can discuss it more there. This thread will get lost if its not in one of our issues.